# what is serial triggering in oscilloscopes? Why was it available only in the higher end models in the beginning?

Tags: oscilloscope

what is serial triggering in oscilloscopes? Why was it available only in the higher end models in the beginning?

Comment: Another thing you could have written there is more context for the question.  For example, where did you read about serial triggering?

Answer (score 3):

Serial buses are very common in embedded systems.  Common serial buses include UART (RS-232, RS-485, RS-422), SPI, I2C, USB, CAN, LIN, etc.  Examining bus traffic can be a powerful debugging tool to ensure different components sitting on a bus are communicating correctly.  Digital oscilloscopes with deep capture memory can capture long bus transactions with high fidelity, but interpreting the raw scope trace by hand to extract the data is very tedious.  Many modern digital scopes have extra software and/or hardware to help accelerate this process.

Serial decoding software on scopes generally provides a time-correlated decode of bus transactions alongside the raw scope trace.  This can be computed 'offline' purely in software after capturing a complete scope trace.  This is a common technique in lower-end scopes as no extra hardware is required.  Serial decoding can also be accelerated by dedicated hardware for a more responsive interface.

Serial triggering requires extra hardware (generally an FPGA) to decode the serial data in real-time so that trigger events can be generated fast enough to stop the acquisition at the correct time.  Since this requires dedicated hardware, it is usually only seen in higher-end scopes.  Serial triggering can be used along with serial decoding to look for relatively rare conditions on a high-traffic bus without having to wade through a lot of extraneous captured data.

Answer (score 2):

Serial triggering can refer to [Protocol Analysis](http://www4.evaluationengineering.com/articles/200911/protocol-analysis-in-a-scope.php) as noted by Alex or the ability to set multiple sequential triggers.

Lets say (for example) that I am analysing a problem, and it will occur if some signal 1 transitions low to high, followed by another signal going low to high and back to low within a specific time, then it takes a pretty high end oscilloscope to set these multiple *sequential* triggers.

In this scenario, I need to be connected to the two signals, and have a scope that has the ability to do this sort of thing.

You would need [something like this series](http://www.tek.com/oscilloscope/dpo70000-mso70000) of oscilloscope to perform that sort of thing. These also have 'standard' protocol analysis software modules such as DDRx, PCIe, USB and others for automated tests (and each are priced as extras).

[Keysight](http://www.keysight.com/main/commonlanding.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng) and [Teledyne LeCroy](http://teledynelecroy.com/) also make this sort of test equipment.

We have a couple of these around the labs and as you might note from the link above, they are not cheap, but if your products require this sort of level of analysis, they are invaluable.

[Logic Analysers](http://www.tek.com/logic-analyzer) have been around for a long time, but the older ones did not have the trigger flexibility of modern very high speed oscilloscopes, in particular being able to set the trigger voltage for each channel *at a different level*.

HTH